# Excel: using VLOOKUP and Dynamic Referencing

Tags: excel, vlookup

I'm struggling to create (by create, I mean; hack together) a formula that will pull in data from the last entry point individual rows depending on criteria of another cell.

I have a formula to pull in data from relevant name:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($B$1,DATA!$C$4:$BZ$64,2,0),"")
```

$B$1 contains a list and contains names, e.g. Bloggs, Joe; Doe, Jane; etc

DATA!$C$4:$BZ$64 contains multiple criteria, some of which are "Class"

The class is either First, Second or Third and is present on columns O, T, Y, AD and so on (every 5th column to $BZ)

Is there a way to ge the data from the last populated cell from the row that corresponds to name?

Blogs, Joe may have entries for O, T, Y and AD but I would like to get the content from the last cell, AD

Doe, Jane may only have entries for O and T but, again, I would like to take the data from the last cell, T

I think I should be using the same formula but adding something to where it is looking at column 2 but I'm not sure what.

Hope this makes sense.

Thnx for looking,

Sam

[Example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1a0V8SkUn4yJG0bVO86cWcwKGtqcyemNq/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=108720054927209113212&rtpof=true&sd=true)

Comment: It may be useful to see some sample data and the expected outcome

Comment: Please mock up a small dataset that represents what you are asking and show the desired output.  It will help much more than words.

Comment: Thanx for getting back to me. I've edited my post and included a link. Had to make it GDPR safe.